# View order schema does not appear using nodemailer but google app script

Tags: gmail, spf, dkim, google-schemas, nodemailer

I have been trying to create an Google order Schema markup for our orders. However, the html template that I generate works when I run it using the google App Script Test

Code.gs file in Google App script

```
function testSchemas() {
 var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('template_html').getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail({
 // to: Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
   to:'MY GMAIL EMAIL',
subject: 'Test Actions in the Inbox - ' + new Date(),
htmlBody: htmlBody,
 });
 }
```

But when I use the same html template in nodemailer and run the nodemailer with the same gmail credentials using the Gmail Service, I do not find the 
"View order" section.

I am aware that to: and from: addresses need to be same for testing schemas  and I have the same to and from address.

My nodemailer config looks something like:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
service: "Gmail",
auth: {
    user: "GMAIL EMAIL",
    pass: "PASSWORD"
}
});

 smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,response){console.log('Done');});
```

Google says your email must be SPF/DKIM enabled in order to stop phishing attacks but when I am using the Gmail service, it must not be the case.

Can anybody tell me what might be the reason for this and the workaround of how could I test it using node mailer before I raise a request to whitelist my IpP to Google.

Also, can we make Google orders to appear as Google card in Google Now.